# .NET in Docker connecting to ActiveMQ Classic in Docker leads to: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure

Tags: docker, activemq-classic

I am working on a project requires a connection from a .NET core backend application to ActiveMQ Classic. In order to test the project in local environment I decide to run my .NET core project and ActiveMQ Classic in two linked docker container.

For ActiveMQ Classic I generated a self-signed certificate with the following commands:

```
keytool -genkey -v -alias broker -keyalg RSA -keystore broker.keystore -dname "CN=dev.com, OU=Development, O=My Org, L=City, ST=State, C=Country" -storepass xxxxx -keypass xxxxx -ext SAN=dns:localhost,ip:127.0.0.1 -validity 365

keytool -export -alias broker -keystore broker.keystore -file broker.cer

keytool -import -alias broker -keystore client-truststore.ks -file broker.cer -storepass xxxxx
```

Then I use the certificate in `activemq.xml` as

```xml
<sslContext> 
    <sslContext keyStore="file:${activemq.base}/certs/ActiveMq/broker.keystore"
      keyStorePassword="xxxxx"/>
</sslContext>
```

In the docker compose I have:

```yaml
  activemq:
    image: activemq:5.15.9-alpine
    build:
      context: ../ActiveMq
      dockerfile: ActiveMqDockerfile
    container_name: activemq
    volumes:
      - ../ActiveMq/conf:/opt/activemq/conf
      - ../ActiveMq/data:/opt/activemq/data
      - ../ActiveMq/certs:/opt/activemq/certs
    environment:
      - ACTIVEMQ_SSL_OPTS="-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/opt/activemq/certs/broker.keystore -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=xxxxx"
    ports:
      - "61616:61616"
      - "61617:61617"
      - "8161:8161"
      - "5672:5672"
      - "61613:61613"
      - "1883:1883"
      - "61614:61614"
      - "61619:61619"
    networks:
      - my_network
```

In my dotnet core project, I use the follow connection string

```
activemq:failover:(ssl://activemq:61617)?nms.AsyncSend=true&transport.startupMaxReconnectAttempts=2&transport.timeout=2000
```

where `activemq` is the ActiveMQ Classic service name in the Docker compose file (I tried `host.docker.internal` as well). In the .NET core backend service in Docker compose file I have

```
depends_on:
  - activemq
```

However, when I start running the .NET core backend I have the following error:

```
2024/03/18 11:17:06.199 +00:00 [Error] Unable to create connection to ActiveMq
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
   at Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.Transport.Failover.FailoverTransport.Oneway(Command command)
   at Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.Transport.TransportFilter.Oneway(Command command)
   at Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.Transport.MutexTransport.Oneway(Command command)
   at Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.Transport.ResponseCorrelator.AsyncRequest(Command command)
   at Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.Transport.ResponseCorrelator.Request(Command command, TimeSpan timeout)
   at Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.Connection.CheckConnected()
   at Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.Connection.Start()
```

Can anyone please take a look what could be wrong?

I did some research.

1. Someone said the domain name does not match that in the certificate. So I tried to regenerate the certificate with `CN=host.docker.internal` and `CN=activemq`. Neither works.
2. Someone said this could be because the self-signed certificate is not trusted, but I don't know how to trust it in Docker. This one sounds more reasonable to me.

I tried to convert `broker.cer` to `broker.crt` and copy it to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates`. Then I run `update-ca-certificates` and confirmed the content in `broker.crt` has been merged to `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`. The error is not fixed.

It's confirmed that if I run my .NET project in local outside of Docker it can connect the ActiveMQ Classic running in Docker with `localhost` as the domain name.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to completely disable host validation on the client with `?verifyHostName=false` parameter in the URL.